# How to edit code for an excel add-in

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I downloaded the Mini Calendar and Date Picker add-in from the Microsoft store and I would like to change a little bit of its functionality in VBA but cant seem to locate the add-in file anywhere . I activated the add-in and it works but it doesn't appear in the Active Application add-ins window under options so I don't know how to locate it. How can I go about this?

Comment: DId you check in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ADDINS?

Comment: Turn off the AddIn, locate the addin file name from File -> Options -> Add-Ins. Look at the Location of the addin then open it from excel.

Comment: @Pierre44 Yeh I checked and its not there.

Comment: Are you sure it is written in vba?

Comment: @PatricK Still doesn't show

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure I assumed all add-ins are written in vba, which I guess isn't the case? Would the fact that its not in VBA be the reason it doesn't show in the active add-ins list?

Comment: You won't be able to see the code if it's a dll file. Most likely the VBA code will be protected from viewing (if there are some).

Comment: @PatricK I see, thanks

Comment: If it came from the store it's most likely a Javascript add-in.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in the comments, but I'll officially answer as it's a common misconception that all Excel ADD-INS are written in VBA with an xlam file (particularly amongst financial Excel people who have just learned to write in VBA).

No. You cannot edit the code. It is not written in VBA and there is no xlam file, only a DLL file, which is much harder to interpret.

More "serious" add-ins, such as those found in Windows store, or are released by major software providers (SAP, Oracle, Microsoft) write their add-ins with C+, JavaScript or VB.Net. There's colossally more coding libraries in these languages than VBA, and the output of a DLL file makes it much harder for people to "steal" their code (as the OP intended to do, even if in a harmless nature).

So VBA enthusiasts won't be able to (easily) edit the code or learn from it.

Comment: Understood, thanks. I managed to get in touch with the original developer and he has fixed the issue with the add-in,which is great